# IdentityServer 4 as Identity Provider for Azure App Service

Tags: azure, identityserver4

According to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/), I can use another identity provider other than the out of the box providers like Active Directory, Google, Facebook. I have an IdentityServer4 hosted as a web app in azure and would like to add that as a custom Identity provider. But when going to the Authorization/Authentication blade of my mobile app service in azure portal, there is no option for a custom identity provider.

[image]

I can't find a tutorial in the web that allows you to add a custom Identity Provider. Note that I am looking on how to add a custom identity provider, not using a custom authentication logic which is documented in Azure. I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on the same issue, at the moment there is no support but you can vote for this implementation via this uri: [Enable custom 3rd party authentication providers](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/13286541-enable-custom-3rd-party-authentication-providers)

Currently I'm busy with a POC so I needed this functionality and I stumbled upon this post: [Secure Azure Functions with JWT access tokens](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/secure-azure-functions-with-jwt-token/)
This works perfect with my custom token provider. Hopefully it does too for you.